# Unable to view an image on apache web server

Tags: linux, apache, httpd.conf

I'm having issue where an image from my index.htm file is not being able to displayed. The contents of index.htm file are as below:

```
[root@docker1:/etc/httpd/conf]:cat /var/www/html/index.htm 
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>httpd server</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>
First H1 Tag
</h1>
<p> My First para</p>

<h1> Second H1 tag .</h1>

<p>My Second Para</p>

<a href="https://google.com.au">Google</a>

<img src="http://192.168.1.6/lord_shiva_on_bull.jpg" alt="Shiva" width="200" height="200">
</body>
</html>
[root@docker1:/etc/httpd/conf]:
```

Some extract from configuration:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
[root@docker1:/etc/httpd/conf]:ls -larth /var/www/html/lord_shiva_on_bull.jpg 
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 jim jim 165K Aug 13 11:54 /var/www/html/lord_shiva_on_bull.jpg
[root@docker1:/etc/httpd/conf]:ls -larth /var/www/html/
total 172K
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 jim  jim  165K Aug 13 11:54 lord_shiva_on_bull.jpg
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root    6 Aug 13 12:21 src
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root   31 Aug 13 13:04 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  323 Aug 13 13:08 index.htm
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root   61 Aug 13 13:08 .
[root@docker1:/etc/httpd/conf]:ls -ld /var/www/html/
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 61 Aug 13 13:08 /var/www/html/
[root@docker1:/etc/httpd/conf]:id apache
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache)
[root@docker1:/etc/httpd/conf]:grep "apache" httpd.conf 
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
User apache
Group apache
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
[root@docker1:/etc/httpd/conf]:
```

I'm totally confused as to what is the issue? Would greatly appreciate input from learned Guru's

Comment: What is the error if you open the image's URL in your browser ?

Comment: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /lord_shiva_on_bull.jpg on this server.

Comment: Look in your Apache2 server error log (`error.log`, probably in `/var/log/apache2`). Also your permissions are wrong and insecure (don't make it allow anything from anybody), and the file owners are not the same.

Comment: Seems like you are not giving apache access to that image. Both the owner and group is set to Jim. I have seen this before and for some reason even if the permission is set to 777 but the owner:group isn't apache the browser won't show the file.

Comment: Still no fun:
`[jim@docker1 ~]$ ls -l /var/www/html/lord_shiva_on_bull.jpg 
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 168411 Aug 13 11:54 /var/www/html/lord_shiva_on_bull.jpg
[jim@docker1 ~]$`

Error Log:

`[Sat Aug 13 13:32:20.899376 2016] [core:error] [pid 7061] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.1.4:38219] AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/html/lord_shiva_on_bull.jpg, referer: http://192.168.1.6/index.htm`

Comment: `[jim@docker1 ~]$ sudo ls -l /var/www/html
total 172
-rwx------. 1 apache apache    323 Aug 13 13:08 index.htm
-rwx------. 1 apache apache 168411 Aug 13 11:54 lord_shiva_on_bull.jpg
drwx------. 2 apache apache      6 Aug 13 12:21 src
[jim@docker1 ~]$ `

Comment: Error Log:
`AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/html/lord_shiva_on_bull.jpg
`

Comment: any update  from anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

The dots at the end of the permissions such as

drwxr-xr-x.

indicates those paths are under the jurisdiction of SELinux.

If you have made sure Apache HTTPD process has search (for directories) and read for files permissions for all the path until reaching the image files and you still get Permission Denied, you must review your Operative System logs relating the denial of access by SELinux.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have selinux policy enabled.If yes,then for testing try by disabling it and test the same.

You can use cmd : 'getenforce' to get the status of selinux in linux and use 'setenforce 0' to disable it.